# django authenticate not working with user created by api , only work with user created by admin

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

i'm trying to generated token after login using drf. i'm using emailbackend for login with email and password but its not working with user created by api and with user created by admin its working

backends.py:

```
class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):
def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
    UserModel = get_user_model()
    try:
        user = UserModel.objects.get(email=username)
    except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
        return None
    else:
        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
    return None
```

Token serializers:

```
class AuthCustomTokenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
'''
Changing Token auth to use email instead username
'''
email = serializers.EmailField(label=_("Email"))
password = serializers.CharField(
    label=_("Password",),
    style={'input_type': 'password'},
    trim_whitespace=False
)

def validate(self, attrs):
    email = attrs.get('email')
    password = attrs.get('password')
    print(email, password)
    if email and password:
        user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
        print("this is user", user)
        # The authenticate call simply returns None for is_active=False
        # users. (Assuming the default ModelBackend authentication
        # backend.)
        if not user:
            msg = _('Unable to log in with provided credentials.')
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='authorization')
    else:
        msg = _('Must include "username" and "password".')
        raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='authorization')

    attrs['user'] = user
    return attrs
```

login view:

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def login(request):
    serializer = AuthCustomTokenSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    user = serializer.validated_data['user']
    token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    return Response({token: token.key}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

with admin login:
[image]

user login create by api:
[image]

register api:

[image]

Comment: What is the Q ?

Comment: authenticate function not working with user created by api but its working with user created by admin

Comment: but you show only credential serlia / view. show your code :)

Comment: also - not working how ? show your errors . show your request ....etc etc

Comment: see the edit and it seems its returning None from  user = authenticate(username=email, password=password) on AuthCustomTokenSerializer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, Great.
This means that  `authenticate(username=email, password=password)` does not return a user.
Do you work with a degugger ? or may be add a
`print(email, password)` just after the auth call.
print what comes back from auth . print(authenticate(username=email, password=password))

My guess is that username is not email or somthing like that :)

**Edit**
How to debug:

1. login with admin user stop just before this line:
   authenticate(username=email, password=password)
   check and print the email and password
2. Do the same with API user check and print the email and password
   see that values are the same .
3. login to django  admin site check all premissions flag groups etc etc that are different between both users
4. try to login to admin page with the api user (set up the correct flags is_active etc)
5. try in the django manage.py shell or from admin user page to create new password for the api user and retest

Comment: print(authenticate(username=email, password=password)) return None and before that i checked email and password printing that why with admin credential its working and user created by admin also working. problem only with user created by api

Comment: so do it with admin. is the email same for admin and not ?

Comment: yes admin email is same but so do it with admin?

Comment: "user created by api " this I do not understand - please show

Comment: Maybe  is_active or is_superuser  user flags ?

Comment: i have register api for creating user see the edit and is_active and is_superuser flag not the problem because i tried them

Comment: its the backend for mobile app

Comment: even its working with user created from shell